# Align "Remember Me" and Check Box in same line (CSS issue with Devise)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Devise with and the checkbox is below the Remember Me. Here is the HTML code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/8zxyz/

This is the standard devise code

```
 <%= f.input :email %>
 <%= f.input :password %>
 <%= f.input  :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>     
 <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In", :class => "btn-info btn" %>
```

This is the HTML output (Pasting it on SO too)

```
<div class="control-group boolean optional">
<label class="boolean optional control-label" for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
<div class="controls"><input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
<label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional" 
id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use: `vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;` for label and input elements

Comment: @RaraituL - this code looks good label, .controls { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; } but how to give some space between label and text field http://i.imgur.com/WkLlBTB.png ?

Comment: add `margin-left: 10px;` to label element

Comment: @RaraituL - Thanks, here is the current code http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/Rxyf2/, it is working but how to align the text boxes and label at the center of the page ? right now they are on left hand side

Comment: Add each row with controls inside a <div /> element, and add `text-align: center;` to that <div/> element. I think it would help you a lot if you would do the css tutorials from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) to have a minimum understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `display: inline-block` on `label` and `.controls` gets the result you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/8zxyz/8/

Comment: Wrapping a `label` round a checkbox is actually clever markup: the relationship between the two is made explicit, and you've made it easier to change the input value by making the whole thing clickable. [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) makes use of it too.

Comment: @MassivePenguin - THanks the code worked but there is still minor alignment issue http://i.imgur.com/WkLlBTB.png, can you tell me how to fix it ? I am using bootstrap and and it looks like that inline-block code needs something more

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez - Hi the code worked but there is still minor alignment issue http://i.imgur.com/WkLlBTB.png, can you tell me how to fix it ? I am using bootstrap and and it looks like that inline-block code needs something more

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and this might be a little cleaner than the workarounds others suggested (works for me with simple_form)

`<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try to float your content like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zxyz/3/
Css:

```
.boolean, .controls{
    float: left;
}
```

Also you can create a reset div just after to clear the content.

Comment: Thanks, this code looks good label, .controls { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; } but how to give some space between label and text field i.imgur.com/WkLlBTB.png ?

Comment: Thanks, here is the current code http://jsfiddle.net/icyborg7/Rxyf2, it is working but how to align the text boxes and label at the center of the page ? right now they are on left hand side

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but i figured out the issue i was having and i hope it can help someone else who is looking.

I noticed that on one of my css files somewhere that `input` for forms was set to `width: 100%`.

Because of this, it was causing the label to always be on another line, no matter how i tried to layout the HTML.

To fix:

Set the `width & height` of `input#user_remember_me` to `15px` and tada, label if wrapped in spans will appear on same line.